# Find duplicate values within the same row (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of addresses and parts of the addresses for some records have been duplicated. e.g. some records contain "London" in both column D and column E.

I want to find and highlight any duplicate values across all columns, but within the same row.

So far I have written the code below, but I want it to work through every column containing values and not just the two columns I have named.

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
    If Range("D" & i).Value = Range("E" & i).Value Then
        Range("E" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next i
```

I have tried to search for an answer, but I have only been able to find ways of highlighting entire duplicate rows or duplicate values in different columns and rows.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and for any help you can give.

Comment: You could do this with conditional formatting, no need for VBA.

Comment: @SJR Thanks SJR, but unless I am using conditional formatting incorrectly, it seems to also highlight different rows that have a matching value. So for example ten rows of addresses with the same town are highlighted, not just rows that have duplication within each row.

Comment: Let's assume your data is in A1 to B10. Highlight your range so that A1 is the active cell (highlighted). Then go to CF, add a formula = COUNTIF($A1:$A10,A1)>1 and choose your formatting. I think that should do what you want.

Comment: Using this formula = COUNTIF($A1:$B10,A1)>1 still highlights values on different rows. So if A2 contains "Cat" and B2 contains "Cat" then they are both highlighted, but if A3 is also "Cat" it gets highlighted even when B3 is "Dog". @SJR

Comment: The formula is =COUNTIF($A1:$A10,A1)>1, you have changed it to B10 which is wrong.

Comment: I've now tried both and neither work for me, thanks anyway @SJR

Comment: Great, this works, thanks @Scott Craner

Comment: Apologies, I transcribed the wrong formula here - Scott Craner has stepped into the breach @GreySaxon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a VBA Solution this does the trick:

```
Sub JustCall()
Call DuplicatedInRangeByRow(Range("A1:D5"))
End Sub
Sub DuplicatedInRangeByRow(RangeToLook As Range)
Const ColorHighlight = vbYellow
Dim ItemRange As Range
Dim TotalRows As Long: TotalRows = IIf(RangeToLook.Row > 1, RangeToLook.Rows.Count + RangeToLook.Row - 1, RangeToLook.Rows.Count)
Dim TotalCols As Long: TotalCols = IIf(RangeToLook.Column > 1, RangeToLook.Columns.Count + RangeToLook.Column - 1, RangeToLook.Columns.Count)
Dim CounterCols As Long
Dim CounterRows As Long
Dim StartCol As Long
Dim SheetForRange As Worksheet: Set SheetForRange = RangeToLook.Parent
    For CounterRows = RangeToLook.Row To TotalRows
    For CounterCols = RangeToLook.Column To TotalCols
    StartCol = IIf(StartCol = 0, CounterCols, StartCol)
    With SheetForRange
    If CStr(.Cells(CounterRows, StartCol).Value) = CStr(.Cells(CounterRows, CounterCols).Value) And StartCol <> CounterCols Then .Cells(CounterRows, StartCol).Interior.Color = ColorHighlight: .Cells(CounterRows, CounterCols).Interior.Color = ColorHighlight
    End With
    Next CounterCols
    StartCol = 0
    Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & CounterRows & " out of " & TotalRows & " Rows analyzed " & Format(CounterRows / TotalRows, "Percent")
    Next CounterRows
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It is hard to understand what the OP wants.  I read it as any duplicate in the row not just if the first column duplicates.  The way I understood it if you put `Cat` in D5 it would highlight both `Parrot` and `Cat`.  But I may be wrong.

Comment: @ScottCraner Either of the solutions -yours or mine- should solve it at least, haha.

Comment: I was hoping for a VBA solution and this solves my problem perfectly! Thank you @Sgdva

Answer (score 1):

for conditional formatting you would use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$J1,A1)>1
```

Where `$A1` and `A1` refers to the most upper left cell in the range to which the formatting is being applied.  And the `$J1` is the upper right cell of the range.

Pay close attention to what is absolut and what is relative.

[image]